# Can I search all twitter messages using their API?

Tags: api, twitter

Is it possible to use Twitter's API to grab search results? For example, if I wanted my page to show all tweets <sub>*(man I hate that term)*</sub> with the word "cat" in it? Is it also possible to get just the matching results that were after a certain date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ah I found it! The documentation is here:

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Search+API+Documentation

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=<query>
```

> Returns tweets that match a specified query.  You can use a variety of search operators in your query. Here are a few examples:
>
> - Find tweets containing a word: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter
> - Find tweets from a user: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from%3Aalexiskold
> - Find tweets to a user: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=to%3Atechcrunch
> - Find tweets referencing a user: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%40mashable
> - Find tweets containing a hashtag (up to 16 characters): http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=%23haiku
> - Combine any of the operators together: http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=movie+%3A%29

You can also add this parameter:

> since_id: returns tweets with status ids greater than the given id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get just the matching results. I am not sure about the date though.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Twitter keeps histrory of tweets which are more than 1 year old. So it is not possible to search **all** tweets :)